# creating nested json string android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am creating json string but unable to give tag to JSONObject in nested json string. 
Here is what I want

```
"User": [
        {
            "User1": {
                "name": "name1",
                "Address": "add1",
                "user_detail": {
                    "Qualification": B.E,
                    "DOB": 11/2/1990,
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "User2": {
              "name": "name2",
                "Address": "add2",
                "user_detail": {
                    "Qualification": B.E,
                    "DOB": 11/2/1990,
                }
                }

            }
        }
 ]
```

And I have managed to get until here

```
 {"User":[{"name":"name1","Address":"Add1"}, {"Qualification": "B.E", "DOB":"11/12/1990"}]}
But I am failed to add tag for JSONObject both for USer and user_details
```

Here is my code

```
                     try {
                     user = new JSONObject();
                     user.put("name", "name1");
                     user.put("Address", "B.E");
                 } catch (JSONException je) {
                     je.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 try {
                     userObj = new JSONObject();
                     userObj.put("User1", user);
                     jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                     jsonArray.put(user);

                 } catch (JSONException j) {
                     j.printStackTrace();
                 }

             }
         try {
             users = new JSONObject();
             users.put("User", jsonArray);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

The main thing is I am do not know, how to give tags to JSONObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the desired JSON String to the JSONObject constructor to do the job. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Just pass the whole JSON string you mentioned in the question into a String object and pass it to the JSONObject(String string). In your case, 'user1' should be the String object containing the whole JSON string.

Comment: To the extend I managing it through this also ...  jsonArray.put(userObj);
jsonArray.put(user);
seems like it is working ...testing it

Answer (score 0):

Current String Contain JSONArray of JSONObject's instead of JSONObject as root element. You can create Current Json String in java as:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

// User1 JSONObjects
 user = new JSONObject();
 user.put("name", "name1");
 user.put("Address", "B.E"); 
 user_obj_one = new JSONObject();
 user_obj_one.put("User1",user);

//...same for User2...
...
 user_obj_two = new JSONObject();
 user_obj_two.put("User2",user_two);

//put in final array :
  jsonArray.put(user_obj_one);
  jsonArray.put(user_obj_two);
//....
```